# Successfully mapping qualia to the physical?

Tags: physicalism, leibniz

So physicalists seem to often try to map qualia to something physical but then run into the [problem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz-mind/):

> Leibniz’s argument seems to be this: the visitor of the machine, upon
> entering it, would observe nothing but the properties of the parts and
> the relations they bear to one another. But no explanation of
> perception or consciousness can possibly be deduced from this
> conglomerate.

I think there is a possible workaround this problem. We map qualia to a physical boundary term. If we think of ourselves thermodynamically and assert our conscious experience is due to the boundary term of our stress energy tensor which enables us to do information processing [(telodynamics)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_Nature#:%7E:text=Deacon%20defines%20three%20hierarchically%20nested,higher%20orders%20of%20self%20organization.). Now if I subdivide the boundary term is no longer sufficient to do information processing. This no longer suffers from the orignal problem.

Is this argument correct? What is it known as?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. On what basis would you make that assertion?

Comment: The assertion that this circumvents the problem? If so, think of it like this if look at the brain and now reduce it to just an aggregate of molecules the molecule cannot be mapped to conscious experience because (in our model) it's boundary term is different from that of the brain.

Comment: no the assertion that our conscious experience is due to the boundary term of our stress energy tensor

Comment: @MarcoOcram I am thinking of this as a possible solution. I am not completely aware of the neuroscientific evidence to know if this is a valid possibility.

Comment: Physicalists do hope to map qualia to neural correlates, but that is not meant as their explanation. Even if we had a complete map it would not explain why qualia are there instead of just their correlates by themselves. Leibniz's argument is about that, what Chalmers calls explanatory gap, not about the mapping project.

Comment: @Conifold can I have a link to this mapping project? It would be a good read for me

Comment: It isn't anything formal, like human genome project, but see e.g. [Frigato's survey](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8511498/).

Comment: Leibniz’s argument is really just an intuition or opinion. If he could have been given an opportunity to interact with ChatGPT, I wonder if he would put it in the category of things that are explicable by physical law?

Comment: @Conifold Is it out of the question that mapping qualia to neural correlates might make it clear that qualia will be present in any sufficiently self-aware, conscious neural assemblage? To give an analogy, mapping the evolutionary concept of fitness to physiology makes it clear that fitness is not only real but unavoidable in living organisms, even though any given evolutionary sequence could be described and explained in terms of the underlying physiological facts, without explicitly mentioning fitness.

Comment: @ARaybould Sure. In the process of mapping qualia we may learn something else about their nature that explains their emergence. In fact, it is likely, that is how research usually works. But it will be something else that does the explaining, mapping as such is incapable of that. Btw, I have a different view of what happened with fitness. As used today, it is simply identified with reproductive success, which it was once intended to *explain*. The original concept (as in Spencer), rather than being shown real, turned out to be a dud and dropped out of use.

Comment: @Conifold unless I'm misinterpreting you. The laws of physics do not explain?

Comment: Most models are a long way from what is usually distinguished as "laws of physics", especially in biology and neuroscience. And some do and some do not. Correlational ones typically do not.

Comment: @Conifold I'm going off on a tangent here, though it may still have some relevance: I have the impression that the early concept of evolutionary fitness was criticized for being ad-hoc and tautological, but mapping it to its physiological, behavioral, genetic and ecological correlates helped rescue it from these concerns. In the case of qualia, mapping them to their neurological correlates _might_ rescue biology from the claim that qualia preclude a scientific explanation of consciousness....

Comment: I realize analogies are only intuition pumps, not arguments, but, FWIW, here's another: biology has a good explanation for the role of codons, but can not, as far as I know, explain why a given codon picks out this particular amino acid rather than another; all we have is this correlation. This is not, however, widely regarded as an explanatory gap creating the hard problem of genetics, putting it beyond the grasp of science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Human consciousness generates broad patterns of recognition inherent in scientific descriptions. Systems in physics and engineering are described by specifying geometry and properties of materials. A natural process is characterized as an interaction between the system and its surroundings although we also must employ concepts of ideal systems and isolated systems in this context.

Claims to an invention in a patent application or issued patent must include structural language to support any claimed function. An exception is called "means plus function" claims where the means to perform the function are described in the patent specification. Broadly recognized all scientific analysis is an effort to describe the system in terms of structures and functions or structures, properties, and natural interactions.

One way to comprehend the problem called the Neural Correlates of Consciousness (NCC) would be to draft a patent claim for an invention that generates consciousness as the product of a physical process where the structure is the NCC and the function is to generate consciousness. The purpose of consciousness could be an end in itself, to appreciate the beauty of perceptions, or might have a function such as to sustain vitality in physical surroundings or individual identity in social surroundings.

The so-called easy problem of consciousness is the effort to identify the NCC as a structure that performs the function of producing consciousness. In this analysis if you take away parts of the structure it would no longer function to produce consciousness. In humans we assume that consciousness is present when a person is awake, it is not present when they are asleep, and is impaired by the use of anesthesia or damage to the body which seems to cause so-called brain death.

The so-called hard problem of consciousness is how to explain the subjective experience of qualia emerging from structures and functions that do not have qualia as a system structure or property of materials.

Antonio Damasio: The Quest to Understand Consciousness (TED):

https://www.ted.com/talks/antonio_damasio_the_quest_to_understand_consciousness

Human consciousness (first person perspective) recognizes structures and functions that seem to be necessary to produce consciousness based on self-reflection mixed with observations of other humans and animals (third person perspective).